# Invisible login screen in ubuntu

Tags: xubuntu, xfce

I'm using xubuntu 20.04 and there is the problem with login screen.

After my notebook awakes from hibernation the login screen does not appear. I see applications running like no login screen is over them, but I can't use them. Although if after wake up I just enter password and hit enter invisible login screen disappears.

How can I fix it?

Comment: Try to move a mouse.

Comment: @Pilot6 no changes. Mouse moves, but cursor doesn't change over ui.

Comment: I'm suffering from this problem several years. I have Dell laptop.
Maybe these links will help you:
- https://askubuntu.com/a/1446916/1731249
- https://www.reddit.com/r/xubuntu/comments/khr83d/xubuntu_lock_screen_invisible/?rdt=43358